# Remove random commits from a single file

Tags: git

I have a single file against which I have made multiple changes and committed each change from a new feature branch. Please refer the below diagram.

```
F0 - C0 - added file "Test.sql" to the repo
F1- C1 -  ++ line 01
F2 - C2 - ++ line 02
F3 - C3 - ++ line 03
F4 - C4 - ++ line 04
F5 - C5 - ++ line 05
```

Where the lineage of commits and features are:

```
  C0 < C1 < C2 < C3 < C4 < C5 
  F0 < F1 < F2 < F3 < F4 < F5
```

Now, I intend to revert the change from commit C3 (ie., remove line 03) from the file using the following command:

```
    git revert --no-commit C3
```

But I am getting merge conflicts.

What I intend to do is, remove changes from the commit C3 only, all the other lines will stay intact and in the same order.

What should I do?
Please help.

Regards.
Kumarjit

Comment: You should manually resolve merge conflict the way you want it to be resolved.

Comment: Files don’t contain commits. Commits contain files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have merge conflicts because next commits contain this line and based on that. The only solution solves conflicts manually.

You can also create a new commit for manually removed content from `C3`

I'll show you how you can edit the history of commits, drop specific commit that you don't need. If you want to have whole commits history only without this one commit you can use `rebase` command.

```
git log
```

Copy hash of `C2` commit. It must be one commit before you want to change.

```
git rebase -i hashOfC2Commit
```

Change the flag from `p` to `d` (drop) and save it (command `:wq` in console).

Now if you have conflicts open editor and solve it. When you solved conflicts use

```
git rebase --continue
```

It's easy way to solve conflicts and edit history of commits.